# Not getting any response while trying to install from USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb-drive

I've been attempting to dual-boot Windows 10 and ElementaryOS, but have 0 success so far.

Whenever I try to boot from USB after selecting it in the boot menu, I really shortly see the logo of my laptop manufacturer then shows a pure black screen, and starts over. It keeps doing this until I stop it and boot via Windows again.

Here are my specs in case you need them:

- Manufacturer: Lenovo
- Model: Ideapad 110
- CPU: AMD A6
- Memory: 8GB RAM

Feel free to let me know if you need to know anything else! Thanks in advance